# How can I get subreddit comments from a post in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, reddit

How can I get subreddit comments from a post? the reddit api says that I should apply
[/ r / subreddit] / comments / article

I tried smth like that

```
https://reddit.com/r/science/comments/qdfs2x/new_research_suggests_that_conservative_media_is/
```

Can You just show an example url to get comments on a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of your URL is correct, except the domain. Reddit's API endpoint is located at `api.reddit.com`. So you would need to make the GET request to:

```
https://api.reddit.com/r/science/comments/qdfs2x/new_research_suggests_that_conservative_media_is
```